# Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type in index.ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've the following TypeScript code snippet (`index.ts`):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (res) => {
    res.send("ciao")
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server started")
})
```

When I execute `nodemon -L index.ts` I receive the following error:

```
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
{ TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:4:15 - error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.        

4 app.get('/', (res) => {
```

I used to write this code in Node and it worked, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can check the types here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express

Answer (score -1):

Are you using typescript ? If it's true change your code to

```
app.get('/', (res: any) => {
    res.send("ciao")
})
```

Comment: It's not a good advice to use `any` here since Express has types and these should be used here.